# Splitting strings at specific positions

Tags: c#, .net, string

I got a little problem here, i'm looking for a better way to split Strings.
For example i receive a String looking like this.

```
0000JHASDF+4429901234ALEXANDER
```

I know the pattern the string is built with and i have an array of numbers like this.

```
4,5,4,7,9
0000 - JHASDF - +442 - 9901234 - ALEXANDER
```

It is easy to split the whole thing up with the String MID command but it seems to be slow when i receive a file containing 8000 - 10000 datasets.
So any suggestion how i can make this faster to get the data in a List or an Array of Strings?
If anyone knows how to do this for example with RegEx.

Comment: `String.Substring` is the way to go, it certainly won't be faster with regular expressions...

Comment: BTW, your numbers are wrong, it should be 4,6,4,7,9 (JHASDF is 6 chars, not 5)

Answer (score 12):

```
var lengths = new[] { 4, 6, 4, 7, 9 };
var parts = new string[lengths.Length];

// if you're not using .NET4 or above then use ReadAllLines rather than ReadLines
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("YourFile.txt"))
{
    int startPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengths.Length; i++)
    {
        parts[i] = line.Substring(startPos, lengths[i]);
        startPos += lengths[i];
    }

    // do something with "parts" before moving on to the next line
}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats almost the same thing i got already, searching for something else, but if there is no better or faster way to do it, than i simply have to live with it.

Comment: @user777382: You might be able to get slightly faster with small tweaks and micro-optimisations, but I don't think you'll find much faster than this general approach.

Comment: -1 for unnecessary usage of List, because the array length is known beforehand

Comment: @George: I'd be surprised if that makes any significant performance difference, and it'd be at the expense of making the code less readable (admittedly only slightly less so). I don't think it's really worth a downvote: if the OP thinks that it's a micro-optimisation worth making then they're free to do so.

Comment: @LukeH. Performance was in original question. We are saving at least a method call and the whole new object creation on heap.

Comment: @George: And do you think that's going to even be noticeable here? I'd be amazed if you can show me a benchmark where the difference between array and list isn't buried by the file I/O.

Comment: @LukeH: Average: List : 11208.41
Average: Array : 7269.78666666667
Array is faster by: 1.54177976795284, Stopwatch frequency: 3579545

Answer (score 6):

Isn't mid a VB method?

```
string firstPart = string.Substring(0, 4);
string secondPart = string.Substring(4, 5);
string thirdPart = string.Substring(9, 4);
//...
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like this:

```
string[] SplitString(string s,int[] parts)
{
  string[] result=new string[parts.Length];
  int start=0;
  for(int i=0;i<parts.Length;i++)
  {
    int len=parts[i];
    result[i]=s.SubString(start, len);
    start += len;
  }
  if(start!=s.Length)
    throw new ArgumentException("String length doesn't match sum of part lengths");
  return result;
}
```

(I didn't compile it, so it probably contains some minor errors)

Answer (score 1):

The [Regex Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0zfk0w1.aspx) would be a possibility, but since you don't have a specific delimiter in the string then I doubt it will be of any use and unlikely to be any faster.

[String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) is also a possibility. You use it like: `var myFirstString = fullString.Substring(0, 4)`

Answer (score 1):

As the `Mid()` function is VB, you could simply try

```
string.Substring(0, 4);
```

and so on.

Comment: I know, still getting a little confused VB.net / C# programming with one at work and one at home. :P

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but in the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace, you can find the textfieldparser and it would do a better job handling your issue.  Here is a link to MSDN - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx with an explanation.  The code is in VB, but you can easily convert it to C#.  You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO namespace as well.  Hope this helps anyone stumbling on this question in the future.

Here is what it would look like in vb for the questioner's issue:

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
   TextFieldParser("C:\TestFolder\test.log")

   Reader.TextFieldType =
      Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
   Reader.SetFieldWidths(4, 6, 4, 7, 9)
   Dim currentRow As String()
   While Not Reader.EndOfData
      Try
         currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
         Dim currentField As String 
         For Each currentField In currentRow
            MsgBox(currentField)
         Next 
      Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
         MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
         "is not valid and will be skipped.")
      End Try 
   End While 
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it works fine. But sadly it's not any faster as far as i can see so far. Still will use that if i ever need it in the future or if i need to rewrite the old code. :)

Comment: @Lim, well I had figured you had already gotten a solution, so this was for people like me who stumbled onto this question.  I think the textfieldparser, while not faster, would be easier to understand.  It also has error handling when a line doesn't match the expected results.  Thanks for the feedback though.