# how to split string by position c#

Tags: c#, indexing, split

I have a text string that when it exceeds a specific length, I separate the string into 2 strings, passing the rest of the remaining content to another variable, but I have an exception

> Index and length must refer to a location within the string. (Parameter 'length')

My C# code:

```
        string text = "Hello word jeje";
        if (text.Length > 10)
        { 
            string stringOne = text.Substring(0, 10);
            string stringTwo = text.Substring(11, text.Length); //throw exception
        }
```

expected result:

```
string text = "Hello word jeje";
string stringOne = "Hello";
string stringTwo = " jeje";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting strings at specific positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185476/splitting-strings-at-specific-positions). Please [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)) this about the `String.Substring` Method. It also seems from your expected result, you may just want the first word and the last, if so, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603911/extract-the-last-word-from-a-string-using-c-sharp) may be what you need.

Comment: In that post, you could use `First` to get the first word as well; I don't think there was a solution, but something like `string firstWord = text.Split(' ').First();`

Answer (score 5):

<del>You have an off-by-one error; you'd need `text.Length - 1`.</del>

The [two-argument version of `String.Substring()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32-system-int32)) accepts `start` and `length` arguments; you'd need `text.Substring(11, text.Length - 11)`.

However, you can just leave the second argument off for the second half, since the [single-argument version of String.Substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-6.0#system-string-substring(system-int32)) returns a substring to the end of the string.

```
string stringOne = text.Substring(0, 10);
string stringTwo = text.Substring(11);
```

Comment: First statement is incorrect. The second parameter defines the length of the returned string and not the index position, eg. text.Substring(11, 15); will return a string of length 15 starting on index 11 and NOT a string from index 11 to index 15

Comment: @RandRandom Good point! Fixed.

Comment: According to the OP expected output, this will not produce what they expect. This produces `Hello word` & `jeje`, not `Hello` and `jeje`. OP hasn't clarified this, but this answer does explain the error.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Linq `Chunk()` extension method?

```
var test = "Hello World Yeah";
var chunks = test.Chunk(10);
    
foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
    var subtext = new string(chunk.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(subtext);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello Worl
d Yeah
```